# Accessing javascript in multiple files

Tags: jquery, javascript

in order to access jquery with a $, I am wrapping my Javascript file in

```
 (function($){
  .....
 })(jQuery);
```

This works fine, but I would like to add another javascript file which contains functions which I want to call from the original javascript file, but the functions are not available.

How can I call these functions? Do I need to prefix with a namespace or something?

Edits for clarification below.
js file 1.

```
(function($){
    JS2_SayHi();
})(jQuery);
```

js file 2

```
(function($){
    function JS2_SayHi()
    {
        alert("Hi");        
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The JS2_SayHi function cannot be found. If I remove the (function($){..})(jQuery); wrapper from JS2, it does work, but I don't have access to jquery.

Comment: This won't work. `JS2_SayHi` is visible **only** inside closure `(function($){  /* ..... */  })(jQuery);`. Even in the second file, below `})(jQuery)` you will not call this function. Question about javascript (not related to Wordpress) are off-topic here. You should try on [so].

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486525/how-to-call-inner-function-of-jquery-wrapper-function)

Comment: Thank you - I thought is was WP related, and to do with the enqueuing, Will check the links you gave.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a **dependency** with

```
wp_register_script($handle, $src, $dependency, $version, true/false);
```

See WP codex: [wp_register_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/)
and then make sure that the second file is loaded correctly and right after the initial script.

The third parameter is an array for dependencies/other "handles".

So..in your case:

```
<?php
    // Functions.php or somewhere else
    wp_register_script('my_first_script',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/my-first-script.js', array('jQuery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_register_script('my_second_script',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/my-second-script.js', array('jQuery','my-first-script'), '1.0', true);
```

Where

```
...,array('jQuery','my-first-script'),...
```

is the dependency of your script which wordpress will handle for you (placement head/footer).

Last parameter bool **true** means, that is loaded in the footer.
Also make sure, that your functions in jQuery have correct [scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript?rq=1).

That will register the scripts to wordpress, then enqueue them:

```
<?php
    ...
    wp_enqueue_script('my_first_script');
    wp_enquque_script('my-second-script');

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I hadn't used wp_register_script (instead jumped in with enqueue), But still doesn't work. The scripts are there because if I take the Jquery wrapper out of the 2nd file, it does work. I have edited the question for clariification.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above takes care of your script loading, but your scope problem remains.

Start by declaring your function as a generic variable, outside the braces.  Then, inside the braces, assign your function to that variable.   Declaring the function name outside your jQuery wrapper makes it globally available.

```
   var say_hi;

    (function($){
        say_hi = function(){
            echo “Hi!”;
        }
    })(jQuery)
```